# Does the margin of error depend on the population size or not?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, population

Folks

I've read in many places that the margin of error doesn't depend on the population size, and yet several online calculators a) ask for the population size and b) give different results depending on what's entered. Here are some examples:

http://www.snapsurveys.com/support/calculators/margin-error-calculator/

https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk/mp/margin-of-error-calculator/

Does the population size really make no difference, or is it just that the difference is nugatory?

Thanks

Remster

Comment: As a thought experiment, consider the extreme example of a population with one member.  What's the margin of error with a sample size of $1$?  How would that compare to the MOE for a sample size of $1$ for larger populations?

Comment: I'd expect the MOE for a population of 2 to be greater than the MOE for a population of 1 (which I presume is 0%). So when it's said that the population size is irrelevant, would I be right to take that to mean that it's irrelevant for any population size that I'm likely to be interested in?

Comment: There are a couple things here. First, there are an infinite number of possible intervals.  Any function that covers your parameter at least $1-\alpha $ percent of the time is a valid interval.  Consider an interval to cover a sunken ocean going vessel once its left port.  Lets let the function be the sunken ship is in the ocean.  Its correct 100% of the time, its just not useful.  If you can construct an interval that includes the population size then you have added information,  but a function without it is still valid if it covers often enough.